# What is the best action to be used after a purchase is made on WooCommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm experimenting with some hooks, but which one should I use to trigger an action when the client presses the submit button on checkout page?

I'm trying to add a QR for each Order, so when the client goes to the place to get his product, the shop scan the QR and that order puts in a 'completed' status.

I'm using the `woocommerce_thankyou`, but is the best hook action to do it?

Comment: When the client presses submit where?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not clear. You should have given some more details of your requirements. In which context do you actually trigger the hook and for what purpose.

Btw, if you just want to trigger when an order placed, no matter is the order status, then use this one:
[Woocommerce_new_order](http://hookr.io/actions/woocommerce_new_order/)

But if you want to trigger only when the order is completed then use this one
[woocommerce_order_status_completed](http://hookr.io/actions/woocommerce_order_status_completed/)

Answer (score 0):

The [woocommerce_payment_complete](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/class-wc-order.php#:%7E:text=do_action(%20%27woocommerce_payment_complete%27%2C%20%24this%2D%3Eget_id()%20)%3B) hook is fired when the payment is completed.